# Unsolicited entries in Tkinter menu (OS X El Capitan)

Tags: python, macos, drop-down-menu, tkinter, ttk

The following program shows two extra entries at the bottom of the 'Edit' menu:
[image: Screen shot]

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *

window = Tk()
menuBar = Menu(window, tearoff=False)

fileMenu = Menu(menuBar)
editMenu = Menu(menuBar)

fileMenu.add_command(label='Save', accelerator='Shift+Command+S')
fileMenu.add_command(label='Save as...')

editMenu.add_command(label='Undo')

foobar = Menu(editMenu)
foobar.add_command(label='foo')
foobar.add_command(label='bar')

editMenu.add_cascade(label='Click order...', menu=foobar)

menuBar.add_cascade(label='File', menu=fileMenu)
menuBar.add_cascade(label='Edit', menu=editMenu)

window.config(menu=menuBar)

mainloop()
```

I believe those entries come from the Python menubar. Why does this happen? How do I get rid of them? (I tried `editMenu.delete(2)` to no avail).

Comment: Looks like default OS X menu options

Comment: You mean that OS X adds these options by default to any Edit menu? If so, how does one prevent it?

Comment: Yeah, it's on every program, I doubt you can prevent it

Comment: Not every program. I don't see them in PyCharm, and Photoshop shows "Start Dictation..." but not "Emoji & Symbols".

Comment: OK, I found a (disgusting) hack around it. Instead of "Edit" label the button " Edit" (notice the space before the 'E')